# how to create product with custom option on bigcommerce api?

Tags: php, api, rest, bigcommerce

how to add custom option like color and size when im creating the product. there is doc:
https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

this is my code:

```
public function addProduct($data)
{
    $fields = array(
        "name" => $data['name'],
        "description" => $data['description']
    );

    return Bigcommerce_api::createProduct($fields);
}
```

i need add some data to product options:  `$data['color'], $data['size']`

how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create an option set, add options to that set and then assign that option set to the product.

Essentially it will look like this:

```
public function addProduct($data)
{
    //create option set
    $optionSet = Bigcommerce_api::createOptionsets(['name' => 'tshirts']);

    //create option
    $option = Bigcommerce_api::createOptions(['name' => 'color', 'display_name' => 'color', 'type' => 'S']);

    //.. create option values

    //assign option to option set
    Bigcommerce_api::createOptionsets_Options(['option_id' => $option->id], $optionSet->id);


    $fields = array(
        "name" => $data['name'],
        "description" => $data['description'],
        "option_set_id" => $optionSet->id,
    );

    return Bigcommerce_api::createProduct($fields);
}
```

Resources: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/products